# Why static members gets Serialized if I Serialize and De-Serialize an Object in the Same File

Tags: java, serialization

If I Serialize and Deserialize an Object in the same File, i don't why static members are getting serialized too, but if I comment the Serialization part it works Fine, is there any to do with them, if done in the class?
As per docs, Static members cannot be Serialized, but the over here Static members on printing out shows the Serialized Value.

```
import java.io.*;

class Student_serial implements Serializable
{
    int rollNo;
    String name;
    String dept;
    float avg;

    public static int Data = 10;
    public transient int t = 100;

    public Student_serial()
    {

    }

    public Student_serial(int r, String n, String d, float a)
    {
        rollNo = r;
        name = n;
        dept = d;
        avg = a;

        Data = 500;
        t = 500;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "\nStudent Details\n"+
                "\nRoll "+rollNo+
                "\nName "+name+
                "\nAverage "+avg+
                "\nDept "+dept+
                "\nData "+Data+
                "\nTransient "+t+"\n";
    }
}

public class Object_Stream_And_Serialisation {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception
    {

        //Serialisation of Object
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/users/kbb91/Desktop/A-B-Java/Studetn3.txt");

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        Student_serial s = new Student_serial(7, "KB", "Army", 9.5f);

        oos.writeObject(s);

        //Deserialization of Object
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/users/kbb91/Desktop/A-B-Java/Studetn3.txt");

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        Student_serial s1;

        s1 = (Student_serial) ois.readObject();

        System.out.println(s1);


    }

}
```

Output I am Getting

```
Student Details

Roll 7
Name KB
Average 9.5
Dept Army
Data 500
Transient 0
```

Output I Expected

```
Student Details

Roll 7
Name KB
Average 9.5
Dept Army
Data 10
Transient 0
```

Comment: Why do you expect the `Data` field to be `10`? It was set to `500` when the constructor was called. And it is still set to `500`, no other code is changing the value.

Comment: Setting aside serialization for a moment, do you understand what it means for a field to be static? Because serialization isn't really relevant to the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @ruakh, yes i understand a bit sir, I am not sure is my understanding correct or not though . 
Static fields are which are attached to the class, they are stored inside the method area with the class and they do not get multiplied on every instance of that class.

I am expecting the Data to be 10, as Serialization would call the Non-parameterized Constructor. that is the output I am getting when I am Commenting Serialization. Moreover, if I place Serialization and De-Serialization in different classes the Output I get is wha tI expected

Comment: @KaranBadhwar Neither the parameterized constructor nor the non-parameterized constructor is setting the `Data` field to `10`.

Comment: @Progman, no sir actually what I mean is when it is getting set to 500. The expected output for Data was 10 and I am getting 500. My teacher has Rejected my answer cause of my output in which I am getting Data as 500

Comment: you call `new Student_serial(7, "KB", "Army", 9.5f)` which does `Data = 500;` which is `static` (only one *value* for all instances - a class variable), so obviously the value of it is `500` (since not reset elsewhere)

Comment: @user85421,hello , but If I keep serialization in separate  class it works as I expected but if serialization and deserialization are in the same class I get wrong output

Comment: no idea what *you* mean by "separate class" - not posted in question - but I believe your problem is not related to serialization at all! Try the same code without serialization/deserialization and just regarding `Data` (usually a [mre])

Comment: since `Data` is `static`, it will maintain its value even if a new instance is created - `public static int Data = 10;` is only *executed* once when the class is initialized, not when an instance is created (as opposed to the non-static `public transient int t = 100;`, which is executed for each new instance.)

Comment: or simply try adding `Student_serial.Data = 20;` just before *reading* the object; it should not be changed by deserialization || BTW stick to Java naming convention: class names usually are Camel Case (`StudentSerial`) and variables start with lowercase (`data`)

Comment: They aren't being serialized and deserialized. They aren't being changed at all, *because they are static*.

Comment: NB There is no [tag:java-stream] here, but there is [tag:serialization]. Don't tag indiscriminately, but OTOH do use the tags that are relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation ... and in reality ... `static` fields are NOT serialized and deserialized by Java Object Serialization.

What is actually going on here is that the `static int Data` field is being set to `500` by the 2nd `Student_serial` constructor.

If you put the "save a student" and "load a student" functionality into two classes, so that the "load a student" class doesn't use the 2nd constructor, you will see that the value of `Data` is reported as you expect.

---

You commented:

> My teacher has Rejected my answer cause of my output in which I am getting Data as 500.

So why are you setting to 500 in the constructor at all?

---

Notes:

1. A constructor shouldn't set a static field like that.
2. You have a significant style problems:

   - class identifiers should be camel case starting with an upper case letter, and no underscores
   - variable identifiers should be camel case starting with a lower case letter, and no underscores

   If you want Java developers to read your code, you need to conform to standard Java style.  (Pick a particular style guide ...)

Comment: ... which is something that should not happen in constructors. Constructors should set instance data, not static data.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion stemming from my post featuring multiple "Student" classes. As I delve into Java I/O Streams, I've been experimenting with various classes, resulting in similarly named ones. To distinguish them, I used "Student_Serial" for one of these classes.

Regarding the use of static within the constructor, it was part of an educational demonstration I encountered. In my haste to comprehend the concept, I shared the code without providing adequate context or explanation.
I hope this clarifies the situation. Thank you for your patience and understanding.

Comment: My take is that the real problem was that you didn't read your own code carefully.  The explanation for the observed behavior is simple, and *nothing to do with serialization*.

Comment: @KaranBadhwar Java I/O streams and [tag:java-stream] do not refer to the same thing.